# Immutable.js: How to maintain immutability when exporting to array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, immutability, immutable.js

I'm passing an array to an immutable list object. However, the immutable list objects are modified when the list is converted to an array which is then being updated.

As a result, the immutable list is still mutable, how can I avoid this while still being able to return an array to work with?

Please provide an explanation as well.
Here's some psuedo code to illustrate the scenario:

```
var data = [{id:'a'}, {id:'b'}, {id:'c'}];
var immutables = Immutable.List(data).asImmutable(); //Immutable list?

var myData = immutables.toArray();
myData[0] = {id:'x'}; //object is updated in immutable list as well
```

Comment: Use records instead of plain object.

Comment: How about `immutables = Immutable.fromJS(data)` and `myData = immutables.toJS()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having mutable data inside immutable structures is almost always a bad idea.(Other way round it makes much more sense). To avoid this, use Immutable.fromJS(data) instead of Immutable.List(data) and Immutable.Map(data) - just as @mostruash suggested.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work fine. I assumed that the data would be converted to an immutable when passing it to the immutable list constructor. Benjamin Gruenbaum mentioned to use records over objects, what's the benefit of using records over objects?

Comment: Record is Map-like object with up-front defined set of keys: https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Record . Using Records leads to sooner detection of errors - if you are setting an attribute that is not known by a certain Record, Error is thrown. It's a nice concept but I'm not sure how it relates to the original question.

Comment: You're right, its irrelevant to the original question. Thanks for the explanation though.